# How does iPhone interpret data from remote control adapter (eg. iHelicopter or rc-car)?

Tags: iphone, microphone, remote-control

There are many examples online of iphone adaptor connected through the microphone jack (+ app to be downloaded from iTunes store) that can use iPhone as a remote control. There are also examples of using iphone with an adaptor and app to control RC planes and cars. I wonder how they actually do it? Any link to creative SDK online or resources to understand concept is appreciated.

[http://www.amazon.com/IRB-1-Control-Remote-Adapter-iPhones/dp/B003E1IQ4Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003E1IQ4Y)

What I really want to do is to have better control of my iphone RC controlled plane from iHelicopter, like designing a new interface. Right now it's kinda sucks. So I want to understand what kind of input/output are being transmitted through the adaptor.

Quite new in all these, any clue to how to solve my problem.

Comment: I have the same question with you right now. Just bought the i-helicopter and download the official app, it sucks ! bad design and bad UX ! I want to have my own. if anyone interest at this topic, I am available via forrest.shi@gmail.com